# Constructing a "microscopic" error correcting code

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, coding-theory, reed-muller-codes

I'm a doctor studying tiny specimen under a microscope. I had this strange idea to "barcode" each specimen with a physical barcode. This barcode is assembled from two pigments which can be analogized as {1, 0}.

My goal is to find an error-correcting barcode that can be physically assembled from these two pigments, and decodable even despite noisy images (hence, the importance of error-correcting bits).

Because the microscope resolution is finite, there's a certain "agglomeration" size of pigments that can be visualized. For instance, a codeword with many alternating bits (ie. 10101010) blurs together and cannot be distinguished. But, a codeword with agglomeration >= $a$ (ie. 11110001110000 has $a$ = 3) can be distinguished.

My question is, for some linear binary code of length $n$ and rank $k$, what is the subspace of $ \mathbb {F} _{2}^{n}$ where the shortest stretch of any digit is >= $a$ called? Are there robust ways of discovering all such codewords? (Is this related by any chance to covering sets?). I realize this is a bit more applied than most questions here, please also forgive my ignorance!

Comment: Maybe use "111","000" as the actual coding symbols, then you are back to a binary code, that is guaranteed to be distinguished.

Comment: This is not a bad suggestion, but for subtleties that I don't describe above, this barcoding technique would be more powerful for a variable length "stretch" (ie. "1111", "11111", "111111" ... "0000", "00000", "000000" for a = 4).

Comment: Linearity may easily ruin your wishes. Say, if you want to allow both 1111000 as well as 1110000, then the Hamming distance will drop down to two. My first idea was the same user619894 also suggested. A somewhat more refined idea might be to treat variation on the run length $a$ as some kind of a reliability measure. Say, if you try to consistently use agglomerates of length $a=6$, but due to whatever reason (specimen motion while the barcode is "printed"?) the run of 1s or 0s may have length $5$ or $7$ instead. Then you could have some heuristics at play when "reading" the barcode.

Comment: (cont'd) For that to work I need to ask what kind of printing/reading errors your scheme is likely to produce? Can we, for example think of $11111000000$ as coming from a minutely failed to print $1111100000$? How fast is the printing process? For example, is it reasonable to assume that the motion of the specimen (or whatever is causing misprints) is more or less the same during the process? If so, then we can account for that while reading the barcode. Not unlike the way QRcode readers have these predefined patterns that a device reading it can use judge the distance/scale.

Comment: I doubt there is literature on this. The only related problem that I recal coding theorists having dealt with is that of *runlength constrained codes*. There the design goal is diametrically opposite to yours. They want to avoid long runs of identical bits. This is because those codes were used to recover data written on a magnetic storage medium, and magnetism makes long runs of identical bits either undesirable or unstable on the chosen medium (don't know which, I never studied those).

Comment: Which brings me back to my suggestion. Instead of worrying about individual bits and trying to fix $n,k$ right away, we should try and model the entire chain: printing, sources of errors (either during printing, the pigment fading, or during reading the barcode), and see how the land lies. For example, if you use fixed width of space to print a single bit, then the length of the agglomerate may be read differently simply because the specimen is at a different distance from the microscope when you are reading the barcode.

Comment: Really, if there is a 2-dimensional area you can use for printing (instead of a 1-dimensional strip used by traditional barcodes) it may well be that using QRcodes solves your problem. Of course, if a 2-dimensional barcode is too large and destroys or alters the biological properties of the specimen, then this idea should be thrown out.

Comment: Yes, I imagine bit shifts like the one you illustrated are the most common errors, as are burst errors where a stretch of bits failed to be printed. 

As for the length of the agglomerate, I may have a way to accurately determine this even if the specimen is at different distances from the microscope objective. This can be corrected with some sort of fitting/correction.

A 2-D area is difficult, but it is not impossible to make a "stacked" barcode, where several "rows" of barcodes are imaged (ie. grow barcode -> image -> erase -> grow new barcode -> image -> erase ...).

Comment: A related question that might be implied by my original question is: how were barcode symbologies designed? ie. How did the creators of Code PDF417 decide the 17-module width of its symbols? Can it be "extended" (ie. PDF423?)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen - "runlength constrained code" - for magnetic media, longer runs in bit patterns are used for sync in schemes like [MFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_frequency_modulation). For drives that use rotating heads, the encoded data needs to be nearly DC free, since it passes through a  (rotating) transformer. Typically 8 bits of data are expanded into 10 bit sequences, with dual sequences for specific 8 bit values, which are alternated as needed to keep the encoded data nearly DC free.

Comment: The "channel errors" in this case correspond to bit fliping, or rather to sync errors? That is, "111000", can be misread as  "111010" or perhaps as "1111000" ?

Comment: Yes, I would think that the three sources of errors are 1) bit shifts (01110000 interpreted as 00111000) 2) bit flips (01110000 transmitted but 0101000 received) 3) burst errors (a chunk of pigment missing)

Comment: It is unclear in your question whether you need runs of equal bits of length *at least* $n$, or *multiples* of $n$. The first case assumes that you have enough accuracy to reliably distinguish, say three ones from four ones; in the second case, just use a standard code and duplicate/triplicate... all bits.

Comment: The run of equal bits must have length at least _a_, not multiples of _a_. I believe I have enough accuracy to distinguish a stretch of three from four one's ie. 000111100 vs 000111000.

Comment: How much information do you want to pack into how many bits? If your reading apparatus is sensitive enough to tell the difference between $1110000$ and $1111000$, then we may be actually able to drop the need to have contiguous identical bits. If the code includes marker sequences (a pattern of known bits) at specified places, then we can treat missing chunks of pigment as *erasures* rather then errors. Erasures are treated differently from errors, because the location of an erasure is known. Of course, if a marker sequence is lost, then we have problems (need more markers)..